# Query tuning using joins

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, query-performance

I am quit new to query tuning practize.
Is there anyway I can tune this query using joins? I am using Percona MySQL 5.6. Please suggest

```
 SELECT
  COUNT(1) actionLogs
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      uid,
      `datetime`,
      subscriber,
      log
    FROM
      bcmServer.ACTIONLOG
    WHERE
      action_date = DATE(NOW())
  ) d,
  bcmServer.NETWORKELEMENT ne,
  bcmServer.SUBSCRIBER sub
  LEFT JOIN bcmServer.SUBDATA sd
    ON sd.macaddress = REPLACE(sub.name, '-', '')
WHERE    
  sub.name = d.subscriber
  AND ne.uid = sub.neid
  AND ne.name = 'test'
  AND sd.effectiveend IS NULL
```

*I am also providing the table structures and the EXPLAIN PLAN for the query*

```
 CREATE TABLE `ACTIONLOG` (
  `uid` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `subscriber` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `log` text,
  `action_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`uid`),
  KEY `actionlog_idx_subscriber` (`subscriber`),
  KEY `action_date_idx` (`action_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=58749391 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

This is the 2nd table,

```
CREATE TABLE `NETWORKELEMENT` (
  `uid` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ipv4Address` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `deviceCnt` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `emtaCnt` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `currentUtilization` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastSysUpTime` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastCollectionTime` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`uid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`),
  KEY `name_2` (`name`),
  KEY `networkelement_idx_name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4994673 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

This is the 3rd table structure -->

```
CREATE TABLE `SUBSCRIBER` (
  `uid` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `acctId` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `neId` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `neUpIfId` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `neDnIfId` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `ipv4Address` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `cpeIpv4Address` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `docsisMode` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `service` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastSysUpTime` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastCollectionTime` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`uid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `acctId` (`acctId`),
  KEY `neId_idx` (`neId`),
  KEY `acctId_2` (`acctId`),
  KEY `name_idx` (`name`),
  KEY `subscriber_idx_neid` (`neId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=17568842 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

This is the 4th table structure -->

```
CREATE TABLE `SUBDATA` (
  `CustomerID` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CompanyName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FirstName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LastName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Address1` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Address2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `City` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `State` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Zip` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Phone1` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BillingDate` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BillingAccount` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AccountStartDate` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AccountStatus` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CustomField1` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CustomField2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `System` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PackageName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DownloadSpeed` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `UploadSpeed` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ProvDownloadSpeed` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ProvUploadSpeed` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `RateCode` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ModemStatus` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MacAddress` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `accountId` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `serviceCode` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `serviceDesc` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `serviceStatus` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `devAddr` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `locHeadend` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `locLine` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `locNode` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `effectiveStart` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `effectiveEnd` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `Exclude` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `name_idx` (`MacAddress`),
  KEY `subdata_idx_effectiveend` (`effectiveEnd`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

And here goes the EXPLAIN for the query,

[Explain Plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jSRd.png)

Comment: show output of `show create table yourtablename` for all the tables used and output of `explain select ...` for this query

Comment: Please read this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/ Pay particular attention to the section on query performance. Then please [edit] your question to give more information.  Also, read https://use-the-index-luke.com/ .

Comment: I have attached the required table structures and the explain plan for the query , as suggested by --@ysth

Comment: Start by using `JOIN..ON` syntax instead of a commalist of tables together with `WHERE`.  Also, use `DATE` (etc) for dates.  Have a `PRIMARY KEY` on each table.  Get rid of redundant indexes.  (Note: `UNIQUE` creates both an `INDEX` and a uniqueness constraint.)  Try to avoid using functions in `ON`.  Then learn about "composite indexes"; that will be part of the answer to the Question.

Comment: As RJ mentions, `ON sd.macaddress = REPLACE(sub.name, '-', '')` is a performance killer. Try to restructure your schema so as to avoid it.